# How to randomly pick who starts a game/chat in a p2p application?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, p2p, serversocket

Hey guysI am trying to make a game where two hosts connect they will "flip a coin" and decide who goes first. I decided to start with a basic code. But I am really out of ideas.

```
Thread server2 = new Thread(new Server2());
    server2.start();
    try
    {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex)
    {
        System.out.println(" Second host didnt work");
    }

    try {
     Socket skt = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 9090);
     String sendString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter String to Capitalize");

     PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(skt.getOutputStream(), true);
     out.println(sendString);


     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new
        InputStreamReader(skt.getInputStream()));
     System.out.print("Received string: '");

     while (!in.ready()) {}
     System.out.println(in.readLine()); // Read one line and output it

     System.out.print("'\n");
     in.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
       System.out.print("Whoops! It didn't work!\n");
    }


}

private static class Server2 implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("Server 2 started it running");
        String data = "I come from the 2nd server!";
        try {
           ServerSocket srvr = new ServerSocket(9092);
           Socket skt = srvr.accept();

           BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(skt.getInputStream()));

           PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(skt.getOutputStream(), true);

           while(true){
               String input = in.readLine();
               if (input == null || input.equals(".")){
                   break;
               }
               out.println(input.toUpperCase());
           }
           out.close();
           skt.close();
           srvr.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
           System.out.print("server 2 didnt work");
        }
    }
```

As of now I put my server thread to sleep so it gives me chance to start the other main(which basically has the same thing.)

I am just thinking how to start both servers, do a Math.random(don't know where I would put this value for random) and decide who goes first after that.

Also, How would I go about changing turns between each host. 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Random;
public class RandomElement {
    private static Random rnd = new Random();

       public static Object getRandomElement(Object element1, Object element2) {
           if(rnd.nextBoolean()){
               return element1;
           }
           else{
               return element2;
           }
       }
}
```

This code will allow you to randomly decide between 2 elements of any class so just put your two hosts in as element1 and element2 and this would return a random host and allow you to randomly decide on a host

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some high-level networking API for your peers, so they are able to exchange information in a convenient way. You can start with Java RMI, to spare yourself from developing custom messages format.

So, for an RMI example:

```
interface Exchanger extends Remote {

    // API to decide a winner
    void sendLocalLot(int myLot) throws RemoteException;
    int getRemoteLot() throws RemoteException;

    // Other useful APIs
    void sendArbitraryDataAsAJSon(int jsonData)  throws RemoteException;
}

class StartupWinnerProtocol {

    /**
     * Sends local lot, picked randomly, to remote end, when awaits until receiving remote's lot.
     * Winner is the highest value. If values are the same, process loops.
     * <p>
     * Since algorithm is the same on both ends, once `decide()` is completed,
     * winner is decided reliably.
     * </p>
     *
     * @return true if local end is winner, false otherwise
     */
    boolean decide(Exchanger exchanger) throws RemoteException {
        while (true) {
            int localLot = pickRandomValue();

            exchanger.sendLocalLot(localLot);
            int remoteLot = exchanger.getRemoteLot();

            if (remoteLot == localLot) continue;

            return localLot > remoteLot;
        }
    }
}
```